# Kernel reports writeback errors on a RAID array

Tags: storage, mdadm

I have a RAID-6 array `md0` for which I have recently started getting bursts of writeback errors in kernel log, like this:

```
[Thu Jun  9 11:56:49 2022] md0: writeback error on inode 1412769769, offset 3035136, sector 285462910760
[Thu Jun  9 12:47:17 2022] md0: writeback error on inode 1412769771, offset 0, sector 285491991552
[Thu Jun  9 13:20:45 2022] md0: writeback error on inode 224524727190, offset 0, sector 288770741760
[Thu Jun  9 13:21:32 2022] md0: writeback error on inode 224524727190, offset 2510848, sector 288770744104
[Thu Jun  9 14:03:18 2022] md0: writeback error on inode 224507073535, offset 5963776, sector 285428442496
```

The sector locations are not quite random: they are concentrated around sector 286000000000. I haven't been able to correlate these bursts with any sort of activity such as high CPU load or high disk utilization. The counts of UDMA CRC errors in drives' SMART logs aren't incrementing when these errors appear. I did a full RAID check (`echo check > /sys/block/md0/md/sync_action`) with the array unmounted, and ran extended SMART tests on all drives in the array, and these have turned up no errors, reallocated/pending sectors or suspicious SMART values. What should I try next to diagnose this behavior?

```
$ mdadm --detail /dev/md0
/dev/md0:
           Version : 1.2
     Creation Time : Sat Xxx xx xx:xx:xx xxxx
        Raid Level : raid6
        Array Size : 164062560256 (156462.25 GiB 168000.06 GB)
     Used Dev Size : 11718754304 (11175.88 GiB 12000.00 GB)
      Raid Devices : 16
     Total Devices : 16
       Persistence : Superblock is persistent

     Intent Bitmap : /var/raid/bitmap

       Update Time : Thu Jun  9 15:02:53 2022
             State : clean
    Active Devices : 16
   Working Devices : 16
    Failed Devices : 0
     Spare Devices : 0

            Layout : left-symmetric
        Chunk Size : 512K

Consistency Policy : bitmap

              Name : centos7:0
              UUID : xxxxxxxx:xxxxxxxx:xxxxxxxx:xxxxxxxx
            Events : 427699

    Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
      18       8      176        0      active sync   /dev/sdl
... 14 more lines like this ...
      14      65       16       15      active sync   /dev/sdr
```

Update: apparently there *is* something wrong either with the array or with the md driver (I have only a 5.6.6 kernel), because I noticed that bits in the array's intent bitmap get stuck after writes to problematic locations.

Comment: Please, [append](https://serverfault.com/posts/1102879/edit) `mdadm --detail /dev/md0`

Comment: @NikitaKipriyanov Done.

Comment: What do you mean by "offline RAID check"? I know a check for MD RAID (initiated by writing "check" to sync_action sysfs pseudo-file), but it is not offline by any means. Do you perform this check regularly (at least every other month)?

Comment: I do the check you mention - I have it scheduled monthly - and I unmount the array while the check is in progress, so that no other operations are performed on it concurrently with the check.

Comment: Interesting. This "writeback" error message is not in the MD-related code, it is defined in the `fs/iomap/buffered-io.c`, function `iomap_finish_ioend`. And it only seems to be used in `xfs`, `gfs2` and `zonefs` file system code. I mean, this is likely the problem with the file system, not with the RAID. Did you do extensive checks for your file system?

Comment: I ran `xfs_repair -ve /dev/md0 && echo ok` and found no errors. Still getting writeback errors after remounting and restarting the workload. The function you mention simply reports errors from the block device (funnily enough it does not report the actual error). Is it possible that write latency on the array is too large and this somehow causes these writeback errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking back over my logs and records, the problem was almost certainly caused by md bad block entries having been [erroneously cloned](https://raid.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/The_Badblocks_controversy) to new disks when I was extending the array. These entries messed up the affected area despite there being nothing wrong with it, and as the filesystem on the array filled up and XFS started using the area, writeback errors appeared seemingly out of nowhere. I listed all bad blocks in the array, cleared them and disabled badblocks logic, and ran `raid6check` to detect and repair any mismatches:

```shell
(for i in {a..p}; do mdadm --examine-badblocks /dev/sd$i; done)>badblocks.txt
# edit the resulting file a bit
mdadm --stop /dev/md0
mdadm --assemble /dev/md0 --uuid xxxxxxxx:xxxxxxxx:xxxxxxxx:xxxxxxxx \
      --update=force-no-bbl --bitmap /var/raid/bitmap
while read s _
do
  p=$(($s/1024-115)) # 115 is the array's data offset in chunks
  echo ============$p===============
  raid6check /dev/md0 $(($p-1)) 3 autorepair
done <badblocks.txt
```

This fixed the problem.